# Small image will be cut off on the bottom due to the end of the div

Tags: css, html

i created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ro2egff7/3/

**html:**

```
<div class="updated">
    a lot of text
    <span style="display:block; position:relative; float:right;">
        <img  src="~/Images/ic_cancel_black_18dp.png" >
    </span> 
</div>

<div class="updated" >a lot of text</div>
```

**.css**

```
.updated {
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;     
    word-break: normal; 
    background-color: white;
    top:0;
    position:relative;    
}
```

there you can see that my icon will be cut off because of the end of the first div.
How can i achieve that that icon is everytime at the rigth corner of the div, but wont cut off. If the line is full of text its ok that a new line, just with the icon in the right corner, will be created. But normally the icon should be in the same line at the end of the text.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a clearfix of the second div. Just add `clear: both;` to `.updated`

Comment: also the span can reduced to: <span style="float:right;"> Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping your image with a span, just give it `display:inline-block`:

```
<div class="updated">
   a lot of text
   <img src="~/Images/ic_cancel_black_18dp.png" style="display: inline-block" >
</div>
```

[Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro2egff7/4/).